# How do you model user roles when the roles have different associations with external models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, roles

How do you model user roles when the roles have different associations with external models?

I have two roles, teacher and parent. teachers have an associated school, parents don't. It makes it hard to model teachers and parents in a single model.

I would prefer not to model them separately as their state (fields) are the same, and they both have a "has and belongs to many" (HABTM) association with children.

I have tried using single table inheritance (STI) which solved my immediate problem, but ultimately caused a great deal more problems. I was hoping for a "composition over inheritance" solution.

Comment: Have you considered external authorization frameworks such as XACML? It will let you express relationships based on any kind of model. But I don't know that there is any XACML support directly in Ruby so you'd have to use an external engine.

Comment: @David, in rails there are gems such as cancan which handle authorisation, but I think my problem is at the database level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to keep one class, conditional relations could help you

```
class User < AR
  has_one :school, conditions: { role: 'teacher' }
end
```

Still kinda quirky, but better than STI

Answer (score 2):

A conditional has_one relation could work for you:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :school, conditions: { name: 'Teacher' }
  belongs_to :user
```

And then you should be able to do:

```
user = User.first
user.role # let's say he is a Teacher
user.role.school # => should return the school
```

Some documentation about has_one:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one